# Compile C# class using SOAP Web Reference into .dll Error CS0234

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, vba, soap

Hello I'm trying to `compile` my C# code into a .dll file to be used client-side in a `VBA script`.

My C# code references a SOAP Webservice and isn't behaving well. When I run `csc /target:library file.cs` I get the following errors CS0234 on com, and CS0246 BbsSecurityContext,BbsEntityResult (Classes within the webservice). It says that the `com` namespace does not exist in namespace `SOAPTest`. Please let me know if I can supply more information.

Here is a snippet of code from the file

```
...
using SOAPTest.com.blueberryhosting.broadviewbbsvcstg;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SOAPTest
{
    [Guid("9E5E5FB2-219D-4ee7-AB27-E4DBED8E123E")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class Webservice
    {
        private BbsSecurityContext sc;

        public Webservice(string apiKey, string sourceSystem, int userID)
        {
            createSecurityContext(apiKey, sourceSystem, userID);
        }
...
public void getInvestors(string filepath)
{
    using (BbsInteropWebService ws = new BbsInteropWebService())
     {
           BbsEntityResult x = ws.GetInvestors(sc);
           if(x.Success)
           {
           generateCSV(x,filepath);
           }
     }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet includes `using SOAPTest.com.blueberryhosting.broadviewbbsvcstg;`. I suspect you recieved the error because the `csc.exe` command you specified included only `file.cs` and that namespace was not defined in the file. Most likely it was defined in another code file or a library. You need to provide all dependencies when you invoke the compiler.

[Command-line Building With csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

[How to use references when compiling c# code via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559125/how-to-use-references-when-compiling-c-sharp-code-via-command-line)

Comment: Wow thank you for answering this question Seth! I will look into this when I go back to work Wednesday.